# Ionic installation after Ionic2 installation

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, nvm, ionic2

I tried to install Ionic2 with no success, so I decided to go back to Ionic but during the process something went bad and I can't re-installl the ionic and cordova.

after `sudo npm install -g cordova ionic`, I tried to run `ionic` and got:

```
xx@xxx:~/dev$ ionic info
module.js:328
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'xmlbuilder'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:12:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:436:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
```

my versions are:

```
xx@xxx:~/dev$ npm -v
2.14.12
gal@xxx:~/dev$ nodejs -v
v0.10.25
xx@xxx:~/dev$ node -v
v4.2.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was to use

```
sudo npm install -g ionic@beta  cordova
```

to install the V2 version according to [link](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-tutorial).

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered that issue. What I did was:

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/
$ npm install xmlbuilder
```

You may also use `sudo`

It just happens that xmlbuilder is a dependency of xml2js and cannot load the module because it wasn't included in the ionic's package.json of the upon installing ionic.

Comment: There was quite a bunch of other dependencies missing in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning the npm cache helped in my case. The actions required were:

1. Install a stable version of nodejs depending of your OS follow [these instructions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/).
2. Remove all installed versions of cordova and ionic:

   ```
   sudo npm uninstall -g ionic cordova bower
   ```
3. Critically, clean the npm cache:

   ```
   npm cache clean
   ```
4. Install from scratch:

   ```
   sudo npm install bower cordova ionic -g
   ```

NOTE: Do not install nodejs version from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS repository because is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to

```
sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
sudo npm install -g ionic
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues while downloading ionic 2. Try to install [node version 4.2.3](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.2.3/) and cordova version 5.4.1 first and then install ionic

- For ionic v2, npm install -g ionic@beta
- For ionic v1, npm install -g    ionic

Comment: I did it, now i get this error: Error: Cannot find module 'bplist-parser' :(

Comment: Hi. Make sure that you uninstall node and Cordova completely before installing it. If the problem still persists, use command **npm update -g** to update npm or install the missing module **npm install -g missingModuleName** . Hope you can get it worked

Answer (score 0):

You should check your version of nodejs. Make sure that it's version 4. If not, uninstall nodejs and install ver 4.
Goodluck!
P/s:
Uninstall:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

Install:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```